# Many-to-many association with join table and multiple aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I'm working on a geocaching application where users can create a new cache or visit an existing one. Here are the models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usercaches
  has_many :visited_caches, source: :caches, through: :usercaches
  has_many :created_caches, class_name: :caches
end

class Cache < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usercaches
  has_many :visitors, source: :users, through: :usercaches
end

class Usercache < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :cache 
end
```

The join table looks the way it does because I've been trying to eliminate any potential errors related to capitalization or pluralization. Whenever I create a User in Rails console and try to look at `new_user.visited_caches`, I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not
>   find the source association(s) :caches in model Usercache. Try
>   'has_many :visited_caches, :through => :usercaches, :source =>
>   '. Is it one of user or cache?

When I rearrange the association as suggested, however, the error remains the same. Is there some small detail I'm missing, or am I working with a completely incorrect paradigm for what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` must be provided in a singular form (the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for `has_many` provides an example for it):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usercaches
  has_many :visited_caches, source: :cache, through: :usercaches
  has_many :created_caches, class_name: :caches
end

class Cache < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usercaches
  has_many :visitors, source: :user, through: :usercaches
end

class Usercache < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 
    belongs_to :cache 
end
```